# Get one specific row in automatically generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am building a web application for the school. And I need to populate a table with data from a database. To do so, I used the following javascript :

```
        http.onload = function (){
        var roomData = JSON.parse(this.response);
        roomData.forEach(data => {
            var location=data.location;
            var price=data.price;
            var size=data.size;
            var available=data.available;
            var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
            var row = '<tr>' +
                '<td>'+location+'</td>' +
                '<td>'+size+'</td>' +
                '<td class="price">'+price+'</td>' +
                '<td>'+available+'</td>' +
                actions +

                '</tr>'
            $("table").append(row);

        });
        console.log((roomData));
    }
    http.open('GET', url, true);
    http.send();
```

With the following architecture for the table :

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Available</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody></table>
```

But then, when I try to access one specific data with javascript, for example the price, I cannot really make the distinction between the rows because they have all the same id. Here is the code I am using to get the row's price :

```
 $('td.price').html());
```

But obviously it only returns the price of the first row and not the one I want. How can I do it ?

Comment: Well, the quick answer to your problem might be to add a `data-index` to `<tr>` and search for that. Even easier you might use the `:nth-child()` selector as `$("tbody:nth-child(4) > tr > td.price")`. I'd like to highlight two possible problems: if `data.location` contains any _invalid_ HTML character then it'll break rendering. ALWAYS ALWAYS encode EVERY SINGLE value. In the worst case it's a HUGE security risk (for example because someone injected a small JavaScript snippet instead of their address...)

Comment: What to you mind by data-index? I tried this, $('.table td.price').each(function(){

                    console.log($(this).html()  );

            })
But it returns all the prices, not the one I am targeting. I need an index, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: ok now I can access the row index using : $(this).closest("tr").index() . I need the method to get the data from the table using the index now

Comment: closest().index()?! Why that? Unless with "try to access" you mean to read data for a clicked row. In that case add `data-index` attribute to `<tr>`, do not rely on `index()` (you know...just in case you'll support sorting and/or pagination). For the value, store it in another `data-value` attribute on the `<td>` or...possibly if you have the index then just read it from the JSON data you saved somewhere.

Comment: Yes I have delete and update button on each row, so I just need to get the current index

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it as below:
Add the index in your forEach and use it as Id of the row:

```
    roomData.forEach(function (element, index) {
        var location=data.location;
        var price=data.price;
        var size=data.size;
        var available=data.available;
        var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
        var row = '<tr>' +
            '<td>'+location+'</td>' +
            '<td>'+size+'</td>' +
            '<td id="pricerow' + index + '" class="price">'+price+'</td>' +
            '<td>'+available+'</td>' +
            actions +

            '</tr>'
        $("table").append(row);

    $('#pricerow1').html());
    $('#pricerow2').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally figured how to do it, I used :

`var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
 console.log(rows[$(this).closest("tr").index()+1].cells[2].innerHTML);`

Comment: While it works, this is **extremely** fragile. Something as simple as reordering columns or introducing some nested elements (for example for formatting) will break all your code. Do it the right way: save a couple of `data-id` and `data-price` attributes with `<tr>` and read them `$(this).closest("tr").data("id")` to read the ID (for deletion) and `$(this).closest("tr").data("price")` to read the price. Also, sorry if I stress this, but you should NEVER build HTML without proper escaping. A malicious user can easily inject links and/or malicious JavaScript code and it is a HUGE security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'roomdata' info should have an ID of some sort, which you can use as an ID on the . Like  (roomdata ID 5), en then access it with $('#rd-5 td.price').

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but that's the easiest way. Always have an unique reference and work with ID's.